# Extracting the last statement in []'s (regex)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the last statement in brackets. However my code is returning every statement in brackets plus everything in between.

Ex: 'What [are] you [doing]'

I want '[doing]', but I get back '[are] you [doing]' when I run re.search.

I ran re.search using a regex expression that SHOULD get the last statement in brackets (plus the brackets) and nothing else. I also tried adding \s+ at the beginning hoping that would fix it, but it didn't.

```
string = '[What] are you [doing]'

m = re.search(r'\[.*?\]$' , string)

print(m.group(0))
```

I should just get [doing] back, but instead I get the entire string.

Comment: `m = re.search(r'.*(\[.*?\])$' , string);m.group(1)`

Comment: Is it possible to encounter `What [are] you [doing]?`?

Comment: What should happen for `What [are] you []`?

Comment: `(?:.*)(\[.+?\])` should do it but I haven't tested edge cases.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus This regex doesn't work

Comment: Prove that it fails.

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall(r'\[(.+?)\]', 'What [are] you [doing]')[-1]`

```
['doing']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to condition *to extract the last statement in brackets*:

```
import re

s = 'What [are] you [doing]'
m = re.search(r'.*(\[[^\[\]]+\])', s)
res = m.group(1) if m else m
print(res)  # [doing]
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor fix with your regex. You don't need the `$` at the end. And also use `re.findall` rather than `re.search`

```
import re

string = 'What [are] you [doing]'

re.findall("\[.*?\]", string)[-1]
```

Output:

> ```
> '[doing]'
> ```

---

If you have empty `[]` in your string, it will also be counted in the output by above method. To solve this, change the regex from `\[.*?\]` to `\[..*?\]`

```
import re

string = "What [are] you []"

re.findall("\[..*?\]", string)[-1]
```

Output:

> ```
> '[are]'
> ```

---

If there is no matching, it will throw error like all other answers, so you will have to use `try` and `except`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findall` and get last index

```
import re
string = 'What [are] you [doing]'
re.findall("\[\w{1,}]", string)[-1]
```

Output

```
'[doing]'
```

This will also work with the example posted by @MonkeyZeus in comments. If the last value is empty it should not return empty value. For example

```
string = 'What [are] you []'
```

Output

```
'[are]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead pattern to ensure that there isn't another pair of brackets to follow the matching pair of brackets:

```
re.search(r'\[[^\]]*\](?!.*\[.*\])', string).group()
```

or you can use `.*` to consume all the leading characters until the last possible match:

```
re.search(r'.*(\[.*?\])', string).group(1)
```

Given `string = 'abc [foo] xyz [bar] 123'`, both of the above code would return: `'[bar]'`

Comment: *I want '[doing]'* - OP. - So your code is incorrect

Comment: How is it incorrect? See demo: https://repl.it/repls/UnwieldyOverdueBlogclient

Comment: I didn't test it but you must edit your answer: *both of the above code would return: `'bar'`* . It returns `'[bar]'`

Comment: My code was right. My edit was for adding a second solution. But you are correct here that my stated return value was incorrectly missing the brackets, which was a typo on my part. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This captures bracketed segments with anything in between the brackets (not necessarily letters or digits: any symbols/spaces/etc):

```
import re

string = '[US 1?] Evaluate any matters identified when testing segment information.[US 2!]'

print(re.findall(r'\[[^]]*\]', string)[-1])
```

gives

```
[US 2!]
```